# How can $x = \frac{b}{\ln(x + a)}$ be solved for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, lambert-w

I've solved $x = \ln(x + a)$ by $x = -W(-e^{-a}) - a$, so I suspect that this will also involve the Lambert W function.

However, I've been unable to make any progress due to the $x + a$, but without it I have solved it by:

$x = e^{W(b)}$

Comment: I am afraid that the presence of $a$ makes an analytical solution probably impossible.

Comment: The most you can simplify this problem down to is $(x+a)^x=b$, which isn't solvable because of the $a$ term.